# MySQL-Error: Table or view already exists

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysql-error-1050

I try to create a table in MySQL but I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'migrations' already exists (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)

How can I fix this?

Comment: if MySQL says there is already a table, there is

Comment: are you running `php artisan migrate` or `php artisan migrate:install` ?

Comment: php artisan migrate

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

Or

Manually empty the database and including the migrations table and then try migrating again.

Comment: Actually i cannot do fresh or refresh. Bcz it is a live database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

may i hope this work.